# how to change key name array object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of task objects like this:

```
1-1 [
  {
    t_class_id: 1,
    t_class_subject_id: 1,
    t_class_task_id: 1,
    title: 'Mengerjakan Soal',
    sec_user_id: '4',
    is_submit: 0,
    is_intime: 0,
    total: 1
  },
  {
    t_class_id: 1,
    t_class_subject_id: 1,
    t_class_task_id: 1,
    title: 'Mengerjakan Soal',
    sec_user_id: '8',
    is_submit: 1,
    is_intime: 0,
    total: 1
  },
  {
    t_class_id: 1,
    t_class_subject_id: 1,
    t_class_task_id: 1,
    title: 'Mengerjakan Soal',
    sec_user_id: '3,5,7',
    is_submit: 1,
    is_intime: 1,
    total: 3
  }
]
2-2 [...]
3-4 [...]
```

How to change every key name **total** to different key name using **Javascript** / ES6:

expected result only change total key name:

i always have 3 objects in every array and i want to change the **total** key of each object to **noSubmit**, **late** and **onTime** based on index

```
1-1 [
  {
    t_class_id: 1,
    t_class_subject_id: 1,
    t_class_task_id: 1,
    title: 'Mengerjakan Soal',
    sec_user_id: '4',
    is_submit: 0,
    is_intime: 0,
    noSubmit: 1
  },
  {
    t_class_id: 1,
    t_class_subject_id: 1,
    t_class_task_id: 1,
    title: 'Mengerjakan Soal',
    sec_user_id: '8',
    is_submit: 1,
    is_intime: 0,
    late: 1
  },
  {
    t_class_id: 1,
    t_class_subject_id: 1,
    t_class_task_id: 1,
    title: 'Mengerjakan Soal',
    sec_user_id: '3,5,7',
    is_submit: 1,
    is_intime: 1,
    onTime: 3
  }
]
2-2 [...]
3-4 [...]
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: I don't see any code. can you provide examples of what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the name of a JavaScript object property, you can only create a new property and remove the old one. You can do that on the existing object, or by creating a new object.

I can't quite make out the rules for the change you're talking about, but here's a simple example:

```
entry.newName = entry.originalName;
delete entry.originalName;
```

Live Example:

```js
const container = {
    "1-1": [
        {
            originalName: 1,
            unrelatedProperty: "example1",
        },
        {
            originalName: 2,
            unrelatedProperty: "example2",
        },
        {
            originalName: 3,
            unrelatedProperty: "example3",
        },
    ],
    "2-2": [
        {
            originalName: 4,
            unrelatedProperty: "example4",
        },
        {
            originalName: 5,
            unrelatedProperty: "example5",
        },
        {
            originalName: 6,
            unrelatedProperty: "example6",
        },
    ]
};

for (const array of Object.values(container)) {
    for (const entry of array) {
        entry.newName = entry.originalName;
        delete entry.originalName;
    }
}

console.log(container);
```

Or by creating new objects:

```
const {originalName, ...rest} = entry;
const newEntry = {newName: originalName, ...rest};
```

Live Example:

```js
const container = {
    "1-1": [
        {
            originalName: 1,
            unrelatedProperty: "example1",
        },
        {
            originalName: 2,
            unrelatedProperty: "example2",
        },
        {
            originalName: 3,
            unrelatedProperty: "example3",
        },
    ],
    "2-2": [
        {
            originalName: 4,
            unrelatedProperty: "example4",
        },
        {
            originalName: 5,
            unrelatedProperty: "example5",
        },
        {
            originalName: 6,
            unrelatedProperty: "example6",
        },
    ]
};


for (const [key, array] of Object.entries(container)) {
    container[key] = array.map(({originalName, ...rest}) => ({newName: originalName, ...rest}));
}

console.log(container);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. so, we able to change each object property with different name as I expected in this post ?

Comment: @MuhammadBahrijar - I don't understand what you're asking there. I think I was fairly clear above: You can't change the name of a property. You *can* create a new property (with a new name) and remove the other property.

Comment: @Bahri do you always have 3 objects in every array and you want to change the `total` key of each object to `noSubmit`, `late` and `onTime` based on their index?